# shareaholic share buttons not works inside iframe

Tags: javascript, plugins

shareaholic share buttons works while page load in browser window(outside iframe). but same page loading inside iframe the buttons doesn't load.

my anchor tag

```
<a href="/product.php/88/1/Infinity_2" target="_blank" data-lightbox="iframe"> </a>


<script type='text/javascript' 
       data-cfasync='false' 
       src='//dsms0mj1bbhn4.cloudfront.net/assets/pub/shareaholic.js' data-shr-siteid='00000000000000000' >
```

```
<div class='shareaholic-canvas' data-app='share_buttons' data-app-id='24985920'></div>
```

Comment: Can we have script?

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).